# Get filenames of uploaded file into dynamically created textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I have a multiple image upload function using (html/jquery) where I am getting the filenames into a textbox beside each upload button.

It works fine when on page load the file input elements are already there in the page.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Ldcp7hoc/6/

But now there is a twist. I have a add button which creates dynamic file upload button and input box on each click.You can remove them as well.

On this case I am using the same code as the above one but on change function is not working.

Html code for dynamic one--

```
<input type="button" data-role="image" data-id="32" id="addButton" 
value="+" class="tiny button radius">
<div id="TextBoxesGroup"></div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/vsbk8xts/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/vsbk8xts/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I tried your fiddle but the filename is not getting into the textbox.Yes probably it's a issue of event binding but not sure which one should I use.

Comment: I have tried with .live instead .on but not working.

Comment: `.live()` is long deprecated. You should use just `.on()`. There's a bit in your code where you're resetting the variable `counter` by using `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having problems when attaching event handlers to dynamically added elements.

Also, you're using `var` in a bit of your code that's resetting the variable `counter`.

Check the comments in the code to spot what has been changed:

```
var counter = 1;

// Using delegation.
$(document).on("click", "#addButton", function () {
    var datacounter = $('#TextBoxesGroup .textboxdiv_new:last-child').attr('data-id');

    if (typeof (datacounter) != 'undefined') {
        counter = parseInt(datacounter, 10) + 1;
    } else {
        counter = 1;
    }

    var quid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var datarole = $(this).attr("data-role");

    if (counter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allowed");

        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({
        'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter,
        'data-id': counter,
        'class': 'textboxdiv_new'
    });

    if (datarole == "image") {
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns left button-mar-top-btm"><label class="tiny button radius multipleimg"><input type="file" name="ques_' + quid + '[]' + '" id="ques_' + quid + '[]' + '" value="" class="imgupload" data-id=' + counter + '>Upload Photo</label> </div><div class="large-7 left columns button-mar-top-btm"><input class="file-upload-input" type="text" id="filename' + counter + '"></div><div class="large-2 left columns button-mar-top-btm"><a href="#" class="button radius tiny alert removeField" >&#215;</a></div></div>');
    } else {
        newTextBoxDiv.after('').html('<div class="row"><div class="large-10 columns"><input type="text" name="ques_' + quid + '[]' +
            '" id="ques_' + quid + '[]' + '" value="" ></div><div class="large-2 columns left padding-top"><a href="#" class="button radius tiny alert removeField" >&#215;</a></div>');
    }

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
});

// Using delegation.
$(document).on("click", "a.removeField", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
    var previd = $("input#addButton").attr("data-id");
    var div = $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    var datacounter = $('#TextBoxesGroup .textboxdiv_new:last-child').attr('data-id');

    if (typeof datacounter != 'undefined') {
        // Removed the var because you don't want to reset counter.
        counter = parseInt(datacounter, 10) + 1;
    } else {
        counter--;
    }

    if (counter <= 1) {
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="hidden" name="ques_' + previd + '" id="ques_' + previd + '" value="" >');
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    }
});

// Using delegation.
$(document).on('change', '.imgupload', function (e) {
    var imgid = $(this).attr("id");
    var filenames = [].slice.call(e.target.files).map(function (f) {
        alert(f.name);

        return f.name;
    });

    $('#filename' + $(this).attr("data-id")).val(filenames);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/vsbk8xts/4/)

Comment: That's awesome brilliant!! Thank you so much for saving rest of the night.Thanks for the commenting as well.